# cannot import org.hibernate.session

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly

I installed wildfly 8.1 to my eclipse and wanted to move my old project from jboss 4.2 to new one. There is a problem that `import org.hibernate.Session;` cannot be resolwed on WildFly 8.
can someone suggest any possible solutions?

Comment: Did you put hibernate-core.jar onto your classpath?

Comment: Well, that depends on your build system. With Maven, Ivy, Gradle etc. you'd just state the compile time dependency in the appropriate place. Otherwise you might have to add it manually and you'd most probably get it from hibernate.org or from your Wildfly modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WildFly class loading](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) is different comparing to JBoss 4.2. If you want to use Hibernate, than you'll need an explicit dependency on `org.hibernate` module.

One way of defining this is via a `Dependencies` entry in `MAINFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
...
Dependencies: org.hibernate
```

Related reference section can be found [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-NativeHibernateuse).