# how to deploy war from jboss 4.2 to jboss 7.1

Tags: java, c, spring, hibernate, jboss

I have deploy my war file from jboss 4.2 to jboss 7.1
after deploying it shows following error (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy`)

bellow i post error that i got after deploying war

```
10:59:04,786 ERROR [org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: org.jboss.security.acl.ACLEntryImpl: java.lang.RuntimeException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:510) [javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar:3.15.0.GA]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:487) [javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar:3.15.0.GA]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:423) [javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar:3.15.0.GA]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:395) [javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar:3.15.0.GA]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:163) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:66) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:221) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:212) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [:1.7.0_25]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:188) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:336) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:498) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:142) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar:4.0.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [:1.7.0_25]
```

Comment: I am assuming your .war has hibernate and javasist jars in its `WEB-INF\lib` (hibernate-core, hibernate-entitymanager and javasist). Can you temporarily remove these and try deploying again?

Comment: I just answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24248534/1535738) related to WildFly 8.1 (JBoss 7.1 solution should be identical in this case).

Comment: hi i had tried this one bt its still shows same error

Comment: actually in our application we use hibernate 3 but while deploying war its ask for hibernate 4

Comment: In such case, you should create a Hibernate 3.x module or embed this version directly in your application. Both solutions are described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-PackagingtheHibernate3.5orgreater3.xJPApersistenceproviderwithyourapplication)

Comment: can u tell mi how to integrate hibernate 3